# How can I find the dependencies in my app that are using findbugs? (findbugs conflict)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I'm trying to discover the specific conflict when adding espresso to my app's gradle file:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

Android Studio states **"Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'**.

[Dependency conflict error in my Android app which has Android Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641445/dependency-conflict-error-in-my-android-app-which-has-android-tests) states the error means the dependency I am using in my app is version 3.0.0 while the one in my test app is 2.0.1.

However, my gradle never explicitly adds "com.google.code.findbugs", indicating it was part of another dependency I added to my "compile" and "androidTestCompile" statements.  How do I find the dependencies in my app that are using findbugs?

Comment: try to use gradlew dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Check your dependencies:

```
HelloApp/
      app/
           - build.gradle  // local gradle config (for app only)
           ...
      - build.gradle // global gradle config (for whole project)
      - settings.gradle 
      - gradle.properties
```

Check here:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:lib')
}
```

Later check this [LINK](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) you have Unit testing support orientation

Comment: I know where to check my dependencies, I have many dependencies, none of which are com.google.code, which implies that is part of another dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following command:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

This will print a (large) graph of dependencies.

For the meaning of the arrows and stars, please refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952415/334493).