# Error when try sync gradle with new library

Tags: android, gradle

I have a problem with library. I copy `

```
compile ('de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.0')
```

to gradle and when sync I get error:

```
Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'. Resolved versions for app (3.0.0) and test app (2.0.1) differ.
```

Any ideas how can I resolve my problem and use that library in my project.

Comment: Probably you should have look int this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/28641446/2793134

Comment: Possibly you use `'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'` in your own project and `'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.0'` is also implement it, but with different versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolve my problem:

compile ('de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
}

Comment: That's not a very maintainable solution. If the test app ever drops the `jsr305` dependency you'll also lack it for `licensesdialog` which depends on it. Better look at a Gradle `resolutionStrategy` to force the version as described in the answer linked from the comment by @nitin-mesta.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the main APK and the test APK use the same library (com.google.code.findbugs) but in different versions (your main APK use version 3.0.0 while your test APK use 2.0.1). So you need to tell to gradle to use for test the updated library.
Just add

```
androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
```

to your gradle file :)