# Android dependency conflict error

Tags: android, dependencies

I tried for many hours to find the solution but could not find. My problem is that when I build my Gradle I get two errors. I tried to look at this solution
[Dependency conflict error in my Android app which has Android Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641445/dependency-conflict-error-in-my-android-app-which-has-android-tests) but could still not solve the problem.

```
Error:Conflict with dependency 'junit:junit' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (4.10) and test app (4.12) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

Error:Conflict with dependency 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.1) and test app (1.3) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

Here's my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "voice.com.topsalai"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.3-
alpha', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. By upgrading compileSdkVersion to

```
compileSdkVersion 25
```

And then Instead of this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Only by updating appcompat-v7:23.1.1 did not solve it. I needed theese 3 lines of code.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

dont use alpha..or beta.. just use the latest stable one..then please dont mix your android support version.. use same version for all android support

example

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1"
compile "com.android.support:design:25.3.1"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1"
compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1"
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

please remove this two dependency

```
testCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1
```

Comment: My mistake. I did not have those line of codes there and those did not affect this problem anyway.