# Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ.

Tags: android

I am new to Android App Development. When I tried to create a new project,Android Project...the following message popped up..

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.
>   Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

This is the screenshot of my project
[click here to see screenshot of the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrhHw.png)

i also tried adding this code to my dependency..
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
this didn't work out. I also tried 27.1.1 and 26.1.0..
that didn't work out either.

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43817004/9611523. Hope it would help.

Comment: Updating Android Studio (as well as emulator and some other stuff after that) solved that problem for me.

Comment: Issue is due to annotation gradle that does not come by default in Android Studio new project creation. Might be this help you: https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/conflict-with-dependency-com-android-supportsupport-annotations-in-project-app-resolved-versions-for-app-26-1-0-and-test-app-27-1-1-differ/

Answer (score 182):

Based on your screenshot i found two working solutions:

**First solution**: add to dependencies of your gradle module this line

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

and sync your project

**Note:** if you are using Android studio 3+ change `compile` to `implementation`

**Second solution**: Configure project-wide properties found in the documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html#configure-project-wide-properties

in project gradle add this line:

```
// This block encapsulates custom properties and makes them available to all
// modules in the project.
ext {
    // The following are only a few examples of the types of properties you can define.
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    // You can also use this to specify versions for dependencies. Having consistent
    // versions between modules can avoid behavior conflicts.
    supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
}
```

Then to access this section change `compileSdkVersion`line to be

`compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion`

and at `dependencies` section change the imported library to be like this:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
```

and sync your project

**Note:** if you are using Android studio 3+ change `compile` to `implementation`

For the difference between `compile` and `implementation` look at this
[What's the difference between implementation and compile in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)

Comment: I would suggest using 'implementation' instead of compile

Answer (score 61):

Add the below line in your app.gradle file before depencencies block.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    }
}
```

There's also screenshot below for a better understanding.

[image: Configurations.all block]

2. the configurations.all block will only be helpful if you want your target sdk to be 26. If you can change it to 27 the error will be gone without adding the configuration block in app.gradle file.
3. There is one more way if you would remove all the test implementation from app.gradle file it would resolve the error and in this also you dont need to add the configuration block nor you need to change the targetsdk version.

Comment: Thanks, Save my time

Comment: @ManikandanK happy to help!

Comment: Praise be to you for giving complete instructions! (So many answers on this sort of subject are just like "Add this: "force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'" with little/no context!  (Sadly, however I am still getting the same build error, in my case _"Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0.
Required by:
    trainingiq:bugsnag-react-native:unspecified > com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:4.3.1"_

Answer (score 35):

If you use version **26** then inside dependencies version should be **1.0.1** and **3.0.1** i.e., as follows

```
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

If you use version **27** then inside dependencies version should be **1.0.2** and **3.0.2** i.e., as follows

```
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: God bless you, may android support libraries versioning rot in hell!

Comment: So Android studio wizard creates a project from scratch WITH errors? ¬¬

Comment: What about **28**?

Answer (score 26):

If you using Android Studio 3.1.+ or above

just put this in your gradle depedencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

Overall like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.Lots of love

Answer (score 23):

This is due a conflict of versions, to solve it, just force an update of your support-annotations version, adding this line on your module: app gradle

`implementation ('com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1')`

Hope this solves your issue ;)

**Edit**

Almost forgot, you can declare a single extra property (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:extra_properties) for the version, go to your project (or your top) gradle file, and declare your support, or just for this example, annotation version var

`ext.annotation_version = "27.1.1"`

Then in your module gradle replace it with:

`implementation ("com.android.support:support-annotations:$annotation_version")`

This is very similar to the @emadabel solution, which is a good alternative for doing it, but without the block, or the `rootproject` prefix.

Comment: Thank desgraci the above solution helped me

Comment: after adding this line now i am getting error "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs" please help me how can i solve it

Comment: @Basant I would need to see which is the issue, since it is a problem executing your gradle, it would be better to open a question for this

Comment: Sorry for late reply @desgraci, i have short out this issue by upgrading IDE

Comment: @Basant glad to hear that!

Answer (score 9):

Adding this to build.gradle (Module app) worked for me:
***compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'***

Answer (score 7):

Don't worry It is simple:

**Go to the "Project" Directory structure and in that go to "Gradle Scripts" and inside it go to "build.gradle (Module:app)" and double click it.**

Now -
Scroll down the program and in that go to the dependencies section :
Like below

---

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

---

**Now in this Delete the last two lines of code and rebuild the app and now it will work**

The dependencies should be:

---

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

---

**REBUILD THE APP AND IT WORKS !!**

Comment: You didn't explain what you deleted/added. What if the tests libraries are needed here?

Answer (score 3):

Go to the build.gradle(Module App) in your project:

[image]

Follow the pic and change those version:

```
compileSdkVersion: 27
targetSdkVersion: 27
```

and if android studio version 2:
Change the line with this line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

else
Change the line with this line:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

and hopefully, you will solve your bug.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way to solve this problem is to edit your `build.gradle` (app):

1. Go to `android` tag and change `compileSdkVersion 26` to `compileSdkVersion 27`
2. Go to `defaultConfig` tag and change `targetSdkVersion 26` to `targetSdkVersion 27`
3. Got to `dependencies` tag and change `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` to `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, in build.gradle (Module:app)
add the following line of code inside dependencies:

```
dependencies 
{
   ...
   compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
}
```

It worked for me perfectly

Answer (score 1):

## [Important Update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52555981/6891563)

#### Go to project level build.gradle, define global variables

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.2.61'

    ext.global_minSdkVersion = 16
    ext.global_targetSdkVersion = 28
    ext.global_buildToolsVersion = '28.0.1'
    ext.global_supportLibVersion = '27.1.1'
}
```

#### Go to app level build.gradle, and use global variables

**app build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion global_targetSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion global_buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion global_minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion global_targetSdkVersion
}
...

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$global_supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$global_supportLibVersion"
    // and so on...
}
```

**some library build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion global_targetSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion global_buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion global_minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion global_targetSdkVersion
}
...

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$global_supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$global_supportLibVersion"
    // and so on...
}
```

The solution is to make your versions same as in all modules. So that you don't have conflicts.

#### Important Tips

> I felt when I have updated versions of everything- gradle, sdks,
>   libraries etc. then I face less errors. Because developers are working
>   hard to make it easy development on Android Studio.

**Always have latest but stable versions** Unstable versions are `alpha`, `beta` and `rc`, ignore them in developing.

I have updated all below in my projects, and I don't face these errors anymore.

- Update Android Studio (Track [release](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/))
- Project level `build.gradle` - `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` ([Track `android.build.gradle` release](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google) & [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin))
- Have updated `buildToolVersion` (Track [buildToolVersion release](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools))
- Have latest `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` [Track platform release](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms)
- Have updated library versions, because after above updates, its necessary. (@See [How to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683327/how-to-check-if-gradle-dependency-has-new-version))

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

If changing target sdk version doesn't help then if you have any dependency with version `3.0.2` then change it to `3.0.1`.

e.g change

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
```

to

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is explained in [the official explanation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#configure-project-wide-properties). I left the answer I have given before under the horizontal line.

According to the solution there:

Use an external tag and write down the following code below in the top-level *build.gradle* file. You're going to change the version to a variable rather than a static version number.

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
}
```

Change the static version numbers in your app-level *build.gradle* file, the one has `(Module: app)` near.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion // It was 26 for example
    // the below lines will stay
}

// here there are some other stuff maybe

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    // the below lines will stay
}
```

Sync your project and you'll get no errors.

---

You don't need to add anything to Gradle scripts. Install the necessary SDKs and the problem will be solved.

In your case, install the libraries below from *Preferences > Android SDK* or *Tools > Android > SDK Manager*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this line under the dependencies in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```