# Excecution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'

Tags: android, kotlin

I am completely new to android and kotlin programming. I just started learning android since yesterday. I have successfully created a project but it doesn't show me xml editor.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
>   Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any idea to solve this problem

Comment: This shows that there are possibly 2 versions of annotations dependencies.

Comment: @KumarBibek - What's the solution for that:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50459498/3395198

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio , click on Terminal and execute this command.

`gradlew app:dependencies`
and then search for `com.android.support:support-annotations`.
Then in your app level gradle file , exculude the `com.android.support:support-annotations` dependency from the dependency which has the older version i.e `26.1.0`.  To  learn how to exuclude go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle).

Answer (score 0):

```
    configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
}
}
```

Add the above line in your app.gradle file before dependencies block & replace compile to implementation.

Comment: i cann't found app.gradle. Can you tell me where is it located

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WYRAPFoC79Gn02EIXBUsYHnTt2WrqcGL

@Nishan plz check this link.