# Build errors after android studio update

Tags: android, android-studio

After update android studio when I create a project I get an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
>   Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

I can fix this error in project, but how can I make my new projects working?

Comment: post your gradle here also

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to conflict of versions of support-annotations.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117626/conflict-with-dependency-com-android-supportsupport-annotations-in-project) might help.