# How to resolve conflict with dependencies for com.android.support?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, compilation

How to reslove Android gradle sync issue:

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' Resolved versions for app (24.2.1) and test app (23.1.1) differ.

The error was created when I added in FTP functionality to an existing app using the pftpd-pojo-lib and slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.

I am running an older gradle(1.5.0) but dont believe this is the issue.

**

### Did anyone know how to diagnose the root cause for this issue?

**

Below is my related section from the main app:

```
//Added for FTP
configurations {
   implementation.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
}
//configurations.all {
//    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
//}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71+'
   compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.1'

   compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
   compile project(':app:libs:feed-lib-Android')
   compile project(':app:libs:display-lib-Android')
   compile project(':app:libs:service-lib-Android')
   compile project(':app:libs:setup-lib-Android')
   compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.5'
   compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.22'
   compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.22'

   //    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.+'
   //    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.+'
   androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
   androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
   compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
       transitive = true;
   }
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'//.2.1' //changes from 23.1.1 to 24.2.1
   androidTestCompile 'tools.fastlane:screengrab:0.5.5'

   //Added for FTP
   compile project(':app:libs:pftpd-pojo-lib')
   compile project(':app:libs:slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1')
   compile 'org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:1.1.1'
   compile 'org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:0.14.0'
   compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
   compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:4.2.1'
   compile 'eu.chainfire:libsuperuser:1.0.0.201704021214'
  //    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

}

I checked out the google site: http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict, but could find any useful sources.

And attempted the solution in [this related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999124/resolved-versions-for-app-22-0-0-and-test-app-21-0-3-differ) - to no avail.

Comment: I suggest you update your `distributionUrl` inside `gradle-wrapper.properties` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle`  version, I hope that will handle this error.

Comment: Thanks Khemraj. The gradle currently in my project is 2.2.1-all. I have attempted to upgrade to gradle-4.4-all (which I am using for other projects) which hasnt helped unfortunately.

Comment: I just answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52548664/6891563