# Android App Development error when creating or opening a preexisting project

Tags: java

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in
>   project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app
>   (27.1.1) differ. See
>   https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for
>   details. Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117626/conflict-with-dependency-com-android-supportsupport-annotations-in-project)

Comment: Please get into the habit of searching before posting a new question.